# ECDSA algorithm in netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

How can i use ECDSA encryption algorithm with a private key to generate a digital signature in suitescript. Does netsuite support it and if not can i use it as an external library?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has jumped in on this:

You should be able to do this in a script using the N/crypto/certificate module.

Basically you'd store your ECDSA cert under Setup/Company/Certificates

then you'd user `certificate.createSigner` with your cert id from above and the hash algorithm to use.

The Netsuite help form N/crypto/certificate has sample code